# Why I use for loop like this but still get an IndexError?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.5

I always thought that if I use a for loop like this:

```
for line in lines:
    dosomething()
```

I will never make my list index out of range. However, I am wrong..

The purpose of my code is to output all subsets of the input set.

Example:

Input:

```
[2,1,3]
```

Output:

```
[[],[3],[2],[2,3],[1],[1,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

Here is the code:

```
def bin_list(bit_len, list_len):
# To get a binary numbers list like this: 
# ['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
    list_Bin = [None] * list_len

    for i in range(list_len):
        extra_d = bit_len-len(bin(i)[2:])
        list_Bin[i] = '0'*extra_d + bin(i)[2:]

    return list_Bin

def subsets(nums):
    nums.sort()
    max_element = len(nums)
    size_subset = 2 ** max_element

    list_Bin = bin_list(max_element, size_subset)

    list_Result = [[None]*max_element for i in range(size_subset)]

    for i, Bin in enumerate(list_Bin):
        for j in range(max_element):
            if Bin[j] == '1':
                #1 list_Result[i][j] = nums[i]
                #2 list_Result[i].append(nums[i])

    print(list_Result)


nums = [1,2,3]
subsets(nums)
```

So my core concept is use a binary list to create the subset list.

For example, when I read 001 in Binary list. I will

## keep 3 due to the third bit being 1

## remove 1, 2 due to the first and second bits being 0.

So if I use 0-7 (Binary == 000-111) I can get all subset of [1,2,3].

But I always get `IndexError: list index out of range`. No matter if I use

```
#1 list_Result[i][j] = nums[i]
```

or

```
#2 list_Result[i].append(nums[i])
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist What do you mean?

Comment: Seriously though, how have you debugged this thing?

Comment: I have printed list_Bin to make sure the list is perfect and print Bin[j] which is also perfect. Besides, I print('*') in if Bin[j] == '1': to count the number is right

Comment: Haha, sorry. I am not native speaker, so I though I might have make some stupid mistakes...

Comment: You are mixing up variable i and j in your loops, try `list_Result[i][j] = nums[j]` to get a little closer.   `i` can be more than 3, which is the length of your list, therefore the indexerrorr.

Comment: @roadrunner66 You are right!! I am so careless.. Really thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of your `IndexError` is that you got your indices mixed up. In your nested `for` loops in the `subsets` function `i` ranges over the number of subsets and `j` ranges over the number of elements in the `nums` set. But you attempt to access `nums[i]` when you *should* be doing `nums[j]`, so when `i` is greater than or equal to `len(nums)` you will be attempting to access beyond the end of the `nums` list, hence the `IndexError`.

---

Your code can be simplified a fair bit. There's no need to muck around with the `bin` function: you can tell `format` to format an integer in binary, with the desired length.

```
def bin_list(bit_len):
    list_len = 2 ** bit_len
    return ['{0:0{1}b}'.format(i, bit_len) for i in range(list_len)]

def subsets(seq):
    all_subsets = []
    for bits in bin_list(len(seq)):
        s = [seq[i] for i, b in enumerate(bits) if b == '1']
        all_subsets.append(s)
    return all_subsets

print(subsets([1,2,3]))
print(subsets('ABCD'))
```

**output**

```
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[], ['D'], ['C'], ['C', 'D'], ['B'], ['B', 'D'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['A'], ['A', 'D'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

I admit that `'{0:0{1}b}'.format(i, bit_len)` is a bit cryptic, so I'll try to explain it as simply as I can, freely quoting from the official Python 3 documentation for the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

The expression `'{0:0{1}b}'.format(i, bit_len)` creates a string containing the binary representation of `i`. The created string is `bit_len` characters wide, padded on the left with zeroes, if necessary.

The `'{0:0{1}b}'` part is known as a format string. Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces `{}`. This is a complicated example because it has a replacement field nested inside another replacement field.

In a replacement field the item immediately following the `{` is called the field_name. It's used to specify which argument to `.format` is associated with this replacement field. The field_name can be the argument's name, its position, or it can be omitted (in Python 2.7 and later) and Python will just use the `.format` arguments in numerical order when its matching them up with replacement fields.

The field_name is optionally followed by a conversion field, which is preceded by an exclamation point `!`, and a format_spec (format specification), which is preceded by a colon `:`. These specify a non-default format for the replacement value. This particular format string doesn't have a conversion field, so the default conversion is used.

A format_spec ends in a letter which specifies the type of formatting we want. Our format_spec end in a `b` which says that we want to format an integer as binary. The number immediately preceding the `b` specifies how wide the resulting bit string should be; by putting a zero in front of that we're saying that we want the string to be padded with zeroes rather than with blank spaces. So a format_spec of `08b` would give us bit strings that are 8 chars wide (or wider if necessary to properly represent the argument), with short bit strings padded with zeroes.

But we need something fancier than that because we don't have a fixed bit string width - we want our bit strings to be `bit_len` characters wide. But that's ok, because the format syntax allows us to put a replacement field inside another replacement field! So instead of `08b` we have `0{1}b` and now the value of the argument in position 1 is used as the bit string width.

I mentioned earlier that the field_name can be the argument's name, so our original format expression can also be written as:

```
'{val:0{width}b}'.format(val=i, width=bit_len)
```

I guess this form is a bit more readable than the original. :)

I also mentioned that the field_name can be omitted (in Python 2.7 and later), which would look like this:

```
'{:0{}b}'.format(i, bit_len)
```

but I don't recommend doing that because although it's shorter it's even more cryptic than the original, IMHO.

---

However, we don't really need the bit strings in `bin_list`: we can just use bitwise operators on the subset's index.

```
def subsets(seq):
    bit_len = len(seq)
    bitrange = range(bit_len)
    all_subsets = []
    for j in range(1 << bit_len):
        s = [seq[i] for i in bitrange if j & (1<<i)]
        all_subsets.append(s)
    return all_subsets

print(subsets([1,2,3]))
print(subsets('ABCD'))
```

**output**

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[], ['A'], ['B'], ['A', 'B'], ['C'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D'], ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'D'], ['C', 'D'], ['A', 'C', 'D'], ['B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```

This does produce the subsets in a different order, but it's not too hard to change that, and I think this order is more natural.

We can make the last version even more compact by using a nested list comprehension:

```
def subsets(seq):
    bit_len = len(seq)
    bitrange = range(bit_len)
    return [[seq[i] for i in bitrange if j & (1<<i)]
        for j in range(1 << bit_len)]
```

---

FWIW, here's another way to make subsets. It's a bit inefficient, but it's ok for small input sequences. It generates the subsets in the same order as the previous version.

```
def subsets(seq):
    z = [[]]
    for x in seq:
        z += [y + [x] for y in z]
    return z
```

Comment: I am still understanding your code. This really help be become a better programmer!

Comment: Can I ask you what   '{0:0{1}b}'.format(i, bit_len)  means? I really cannot understand what it is. Thank you :)

Comment: @MarsLee: Sure! I've added some more info to my answer.

Comment: This is super clear! Really thank you for spend extra time explaining this for me. I learn a lots! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an error because of the following:

1. `len(nums) == 3`
2. `size_subset == 2**3 == 8`
3. `nums[3]` is being accessed in the loop where `i` goes from `0` to `len[list_Bin]`.

The solution is probably to access `nums[j]` instead of `nums[i]` since `j` goes from `0` to `len(nums)`.